# How to pass Enum to function and how to evaluate enum in if statement c#

Tags: c#, enums

suppose i have class which has one enum. so when some one will call class function then they will send a enum value to function and from function we like to use if statement to check what value has been sent.

```
public class BBALogger
{
enum MsgType
{
    Error ,
    Info 
}

public void WriteToLog(String inLogMessage, Enum msgtype)
{
     if(msgtype==MsgType.Error)
     {

     }
     else if(msgtype==MsgType.info)
     {

     }
}
}
```

calling function like this way

```
class BBALogger x = new BBALogger()
x.WriteToLog("Hello",MsgType.Error);
```

i am getting error. where i am making the mistake.

Comment: I suppose that function header should look like `public void WriteToLog(String inLogMessage, MsgType msgtype)` rather. Enum is general type for enum, you need a concrete enum.

Comment: You must either declare the enum outside your class or make it public and use the qualified name `BBALogger.MsgType`

Comment: The way you create an instance of the `BBALogger` class is also invalid, you use `class BBALogger x = new BBALogger()`, this will not compile... you probably need something like `var x = new BBALogger();` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `MsgType` instead of `Enum`

```
public void WriteToLog(String inLogMessage, MsgType msgtype)
{
     if(msgtype==MsgType.Error)
     {

     }
     else if(msgtype==MsgType.info)
     {

     }
}
```